# context sensitive menu for a grid using a menu class

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a context menu for my gridcontrol.

```
theGrid.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
This has add, delete, edit as the choices.
```

How can I create a menu class and use for the choices in the contextmenustrip. 
Can anyone show me some sample code to do this.

Thanks
Sun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.aspx) has information on how to add items to a `contextmenustrip`

Sample Code:

```
// Declare the ContextMenuStrip control.
    private ContextMenuStrip fruitContextMenuStrip;

    public Form3()
    {
        // Create a new ContextMenuStrip control.
        fruitContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();

        // Attach an event handler for the 
        // ContextMenuStrip control's Opening event.
        fruitContextMenuStrip.Opening += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(cms_Opening);

        // Create a new ToolStrip control.
        ToolStrip ts = new ToolStrip();

        // Create a ToolStripDropDownButton control and add it
        // to the ToolStrip control's Items collections.
        ToolStripDropDownButton fruitToolStripDropDownButton = new ToolStripDropDownButton("Fruit", null, null, "Fruit");
        ts.Items.Add(fruitToolStripDropDownButton);

        // Dock the ToolStrip control to the top of the form.
        ts.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

        // Assign the ContextMenuStrip control as the 
        // ToolStripDropDownButton control's DropDown menu.
        fruitToolStripDropDownButton.DropDown = fruitContextMenuStrip;

        // Create a new MenuStrip control and add a ToolStripMenuItem.
        MenuStrip ms = new MenuStrip();
        ToolStripMenuItem fruitToolStripMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem("Fruit", null, null, "Fruit");
        ms.Items.Add(fruitToolStripMenuItem);

        // Dock the MenuStrip control to the top of the form.
        ms.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

        // Assign the MenuStrip control as the 
        // ToolStripMenuItem's DropDown menu.
        fruitToolStripMenuItem.DropDown = fruitContextMenuStrip;

        // Assign the ContextMenuStrip to the form's 
        // ContextMenuStrip property.
        this.ContextMenuStrip = fruitContextMenuStrip;

        // Add the ToolStrip control to the Controls collection.
        this.Controls.Add(ts);

        //Add a button to the form and assign its ContextMenuStrip.
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(60, 60);
        this.Controls.Add(b);
        b.ContextMenuStrip = fruitContextMenuStrip;

        // Add the MenuStrip control last.
        // This is important for correct placement in the z-order.
        this.Controls.Add(ms);
    }
```

Or another link to [ContextMenuStrip in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/context-menu-in-C-Sharp/)